# How to find a list for each column index containing the row indices for the n minimum values?

Tags: python, list, numpy, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have the distances between 60 delivery and 6 receiving points stored in the following list of a list (60 rows x 6 columns). Each column index is an id for the receiving point. Each row index is an id for a delivery point & values in each row contains the distance values between receiving and delivery points. I would like the output to be a list of a list, the first list should be for the first receiving point containing the Id of the delivery point (i.e. row index) nearest to it (i.e. those with the minimum distance). If the receiving point has more than 10 ids, the second receiving point should take the index of the delivery point.

```
[[8.8571112536429428, 8.9401324296172984, 11.610640135587387, 13.695908399729435, 14.239701934343463, 16.347271804009676], [9.1542700414794123, 9.301375660862357, 12.042023807282666, 14.278330930177338, 14.822147396293593, 16.926281570649053], [9.3549480280083053, 9.4363340620527882, 12.0922348611257, 13.959594685254489, 14.499353590653021, 16.657032572800848], [9.6487557392404799, 9.7657869305623226, 12.460747138875766, 14.374363831842004, 14.913246132168481, 17.078816216816612], [9.8500830619048756, 9.941928195489762, 12.600424422369565, 14.320647726487726, 14.856529889513659, 17.053401733435681], [10.208637100585225, 10.207676145898613, 12.723522650837346, 13.856177303497407, 14.382791865423997, 16.658587307014372], [10.1910872674719, 10.037355180092288, 12.283344476416266, 12.66725004132222, 13.183857132732589, 15.526690228503712], [10.167102743733482, 9.9524125047033163, 12.07343660126983, 12.162682014308746, 12.675617848939511, 15.039512303870563], [10.090871086547825, 9.8115213211525898, 11.790126440337367, 11.593233926195705, 12.103574298115904, 14.4820293513395], [9.5274386079952311, 9.3526986516250226, 11.585339019955278, 12.218449369065173, 12.744717298249004, 15.029533890574408], [8.220431544246674, 8.1871820395080306, 6.6144875520750475, 13.992293052552345, 14.331397784009633, 14.059961596343157], [7.9204103100031089, 7.9698068552556149, 6.7155093848996588, 14.257923888026014, 14.615784279583281, 14.449918280409948], [9.7135759858996735, 9.6746983762992613, 7.8803297497398228, 14.876430368853811, 15.169432219711698, 14.60912585951378], [9.4094955419366002, 9.4098722332874605, 7.7674718374559681, 14.927743015130112, 15.236306897790202, 14.761615339497585], [9.2122408466853098, 9.1881250247309083, 7.4942137402393918, 14.647946737872344, 14.958143976136816, 14.50013742929014], [8.9841934720188092, 8.8520065421095069, 6.8626506854553613, 13.831477987463257, 14.132583493256959, 13.647221016966505], [9.5840483074527274, 9.2941594702052885, 6.8164835478554302, 13.046024885802945, 13.301229533671846, 12.594096236183471], [9.9445372122605349, 9.6058614400636344, 6.9916200564550426, 12.835254578479189, 13.067358236389927, 12.248723563747451], [10.416198053229536, 10.038019172566832, 7.320744269707677, 12.724667844353796, 12.928853613651627, 11.974782965066465], [8.3726156127310514, 8.0335106590514389, 5.5418676073077071, 12.193703516957356, 12.4955241944979, 12.074184014412694], [15.343282837426498, 14.612810748021396, 11.719837176504152, 10.815363143002003, 10.61704360015848, 8.1978064656896166], [14.763900069696792, 14.036444869869143, 11.139254046384917, 10.507037580860795, 10.341445856746137, 8.0158204757921609], [15.050519252702051, 14.304472484980723, 11.444343208498724, 10.317148429543209, 10.11832886496242, 7.7084235654966227], [14.633395741678543, 13.884783308045476, 11.032004790258792, 10.008341293867591, 9.8302540420848139, 7.4838052876071925], [14.687538814297087, 13.928120554701081, 11.102101753634196, 9.8143890338406727, 9.6221844290320888, 7.242858836040198], [16.206771343990855, 15.423094868219572, 12.667874155296383, 10.592013153020433, 10.341381213002265, 7.828128689132094], [15.619986824578037, 14.839512805989022, 12.07134562493208, 9.941248894014036, 9.6730238906659896, 7.1204847032362064], [15.466510837719252, 14.722650885781356, 11.859584227303976, 11.005355907973096, 10.841457181104625, 8.5355793396076542], [15.881628044920925, 15.114979112353129, 12.303781665228508, 10.431552266627245, 10.168094895619543, 7.6172562892884867], [15.990055281404205, 15.228998548281766, 12.402303221302091, 10.628004725315831, 10.366298047990778, 7.8161346563914886], [15.736154746045536, 15.105060475683793, 15.655389922101902, 10.257378116673564, 10.437487648335722, 12.986975605774582], [15.548179177256573, 14.94440218395493, 15.626456150675166, 10.546940280185749, 10.759208435116861, 13.341769506218135], [16.056200839858427, 15.443052455414923, 16.067256415048941, 10.75556596930948, 10.936300952104936, 13.484265936117088], [16.030713205411661, 15.438181246885511, 16.155466542456864, 11.045800849955867, 11.244929483214554, 13.812515619985064], [16.313052682304914, 15.720770108649377, 16.431112335118467, 11.249958108935862, 11.437150989913047, 13.990677762284269], [18.105447981028753, 17.497815792108987, 18.118444773387797, 12.607951345201421, 12.74911601436634, 15.240500388084236], [17.142295998639362, 16.516014456952504, 17.049403499471961, 11.356260920035698, 11.477709879833039, 13.940757339137166], [16.880960363087262, 16.295391156594004, 17.047298473739879, 12.042815464061373, 12.253838789738293, 14.833741298425258], [16.829066450969425, 16.186260528460714, 16.648467871695775, 10.863969840137969, 10.981264441642955, 13.441364459426584], [16.706770057748134, 16.057278389618567, 16.489880994158096, 10.66731590031403, 10.782806110209037, 13.241623134667138], [6.2381381218067373, 6.2194888862642577, 5.3123877587192734, 13.032731934009478, 13.436570966737028, 13.604318730460024], [5.9396526675633359, 6.0510670977394989, 5.6550994902754956, 13.377297348970819, 13.796901168827901, 14.061779244814891], [5.7459686443632254, 5.7337795314951476, 5.128072879443855, 12.839514057015172, 13.259457905642641, 13.544229052525234], [5.4396818820127448, 5.5212829292054373, 5.3478158305128609, 13.015711451040913, 13.448367961719672, 13.817821744765213], [5.2486124965428793, 5.2771383616456671, 5.1280728794438764, 12.761792631597269, 13.198552383994748, 13.606301100241394], [5.1357507357534091, 4.8934821813911116, 4.3425562735183956, 11.909231180299701, 12.347349228460095, 12.796008934616751], [6.0624496974579065, 5.5239362160282885, 3.2608073018340953, 10.803317648207225, 11.212939401191328, 11.513024080838051], [6.541065357416608, 5.9465219070465052, 3.21987168560677, 10.433571173595469, 10.825594109895922, 11.031083867922506], [7.1018039265314412, 6.4759823196077377, 3.5879904824168545, 10.133155083894605, 10.500290611504337, 10.569106489501804], [6.6159847203117996, 6.1484976847959834, 3.693862394938451, 11.104160934731619, 11.485287311220674, 11.58502506380087], [13.430750084712624, 12.586122124543479, 10.179997227804684, 6.8411749179384573, 6.6360404138368807, 4.4413375942891191], [12.860249089041771, 12.013111253910548, 9.6424305371007595, 6.5265483990909088, 6.3870431740969478, 4.5327714458446025], [13.272600943061237, 12.417526751742299, 10.11455042396398, 6.3481713853356778, 6.1413498052896012, 4.0598343957949465], [12.899680340493058, 12.040738918624724, 9.7922256763619799, 6.0320947971518875, 5.8694747994377581, 4.0961285664368985], [13.039043430532091, 12.175521475480428, 9.9819378451487175, 5.846777676230575, 5.6537489732340989, 3.8430711005412199], [14.743170256318038, 13.872379058466487, 11.772960143566037, 6.7282980603815119, 6.4067364710835779, 4.1781427489974972], [14.104799998788597, 13.236833606935109, 11.078799794841727, 6.1159297631963634, 5.7670825457695942, 3.3073563334009304], [13.704976338118522, 12.847247158071006, 10.590221043670937, 7.0291094112573935, 6.8972824227028688, 5.2571510859283084], [14.230441720137883, 13.369755506528303, 11.107917378625881, 6.5757610778969147, 6.2444587313792308, 3.719834427050813], [14.286267358713269, 13.42888235219627, 11.127661155677838, 6.7622316296131206, 6.4369851286351629, 3.9009661834155436]]
```

my code looks like the following which is not working:

```
def GetDistance(i,k): 
   distance = 4.1*(i**2) - 6.2*(k**2) 
   return distance 
def my_min(sequence):
   low = sequence[0] 
   for i in sequence:
       if i < low:
          low = i
   return sequence.index(low)
list = []
listOflist = []
numberOfrows = 60
numberOfcolumns = 6
for i in range(numberOfrows):
  for k in range(numberOfcolumns): 
      distance = GetDistance(i,k) ## get the distance value from another function
      list.append(distance)
   columnIndex = my_min(list[numberOfcolumns*i:(i+1)*numberOfcolumns])
   columnIndices.append(columnIndex)
```

The desired results look something like this:

```
listOflist = [[rowId,rowId,rowId,rowId,rowId,rowId,rowId,rowId,rowId,rowId] # This is the list of the first column index and the values inside are the row indices with top 10  minimum values ,[3,14,42,35,53,27,19,0,34,22,7] # second column index with the row indices of the top 10 values,...
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: `[2,52,32,43,12,31,45,59,1,9]` are not the indices of top 10 minimum values of 1st column. The values which I get for first column are `[45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 46, 40, 47, 49, 48]`. Can you check your desired output? I also do not see any connection between your output and the `distance` which is returned from `GetDistance`. You wrote that you need top 10 minimum values. How is `distance` involved here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt based on my understanding of your question, desired output and data. I converted the data into an array to make use of `np.argsort()`. It returns the indices of the sorted array and since you are interested in top 10 `n=10`, you can use slicing `[0:n]` to get only the indices of top 10 minimum values. `data[:,i]` gives you the values of `i`th column. The value of `i` varies from `0` to `5` since you have 6 columns in total. Finally, you do all these operations using a list comprehension which is the third line of the code below. **P.S: In case the below output is not what you want, let me know and I will update my solution accordingly.**

```
data = np.array([[8.8571112536429428, 8.9401324296172984...]])
n = 10 # For top n minimum values
listOflist = [list(np.argsort(data[:,i])[0:n]) for i in range(numberOfcolumns)]
print (listOflist)
```

**Output**

```
[[45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 46, 40, 47, 49, 48], [45, 44, 43, 46, 42, 47, 41, 49, 40, 48], ...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. Sorry I may have not asked the question correctly. To explain more, Let us say I have 60 delivery and 6 receiving points. Each column index is an id for the receiving point. Each row index is an id for a delivery point & values in the row contain distance between receiving and delivery points. I would like the output to be a list of each receiving point containing the Id of the delivery point (i.e. row index) nearest to the delivery point (min distance). If the receiving point has more than 10, the second receiving point should take the index of the delivery point.

Answer (score 0):

This might be way simpler as you think.
Read your data:

```
data = np.array(the array that u gave us above)
```

and then you can read column by column using numpy formatting:

```
min_0_indices.append(np.argmin(data[:, [0]]))
```

the ":" means every line in column "0". Also with np.argmin we get the index of the minimum.

And then we can set the value of data[index][0] = 100 so when we repeat the search for a minimum it doesn't get picked again.

```
data[np.argmin(data[:, [0]])][0] = 100
```

Now we have the normal array min_0_indices which contains the top 10 minimum values if you repeat all that (except reading data) 10 times.
To get other columns just replace the [0] with the columnnuber.